# What is the probability that you get $i$ on the $i^{th}$ trial?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the probability that you get $i$ on the $i^{th}$ trial?

Match = Get result $i$ on $i^{th}$ trial. What is the probability of $M = 0,1,2,...,6$ matches when:

Note: I'm not asking you to do both parts. I've got part (a) but I'm just including it in case it helps in some way.

a) rolling a die 6 times

So with this one. Clearly each time you roll the dice again, there is still a possibility of 6 numbers.

Let $A_n$ denote the event that you get $n$ matches (i.e. In all 6 rolls, only n of them ended up with the number on the die equal to the number of that particular trial in order)

$$P(A_0) = \frac{5^6 \times \frac{6!}{6!}}{6^6}$$

$$P(A_1) = \frac{5^5 \times \frac{6!}{5!1!}}{6^6}$$

$$P(A_2) = \frac{5^4 \times \frac{6!}{4!2!}}{6^6}$$

etc...

So the general idea was that if there are $4$ rolls where you do not get a match in any of them then you say $5^4$ because there are $5$ numbers in each trial that you can get that are not matches. With the remaining rolls where you must get a match (2 of them here), there is only 1 number (the match). You then sort it by saying $6! \div$ $4!2!$ because you treat the rolls where you do not get a match as identical and the same goes for the ones where you do. You do this because you are only interested in the difference between whether they are matches or not.

b) dealing 6 cards numbered $1$ to $6$ face up.

I understand the question. On the first deal you must get the card numbered $1$, etc.

In the denominator we now use $6!=720$ as opposed to $6^6$

Now the numerator is the funny part.

Let $B_n =$ the event that you get $n$ matches.

So for $B_0$ how would you do the numerator. I feel like my method doesn't apply here anymore?

Comment: $B_0$ is called a 'derangement'.  The number of derangements equals the closest integer to $6!/e$, where $e=2.7182818$ is the famous number.  Other $B_j$ are also awkward.  $B_5$ is easy though.

Comment: The **places** we have a match can be chosen in $\binom{6}{k}$ ways. We want also no match in the $6-k$ places. This is the number of derangements of $6-k$ objects. For detail about how to count this, please see Wikipedia, derangements.

Answer (score 1):

OK, $B_0$ is the ways you get no match, using Inclusion-Exclusion Principle where $a_i$ is the probability that $i$ is in correct place:
$$P\left(\sum a_i\right)=S-1-S_2+S_3...$$
And now ${\rm P}(\text{none in correct place})+{\rm P}(\text{atleats one in correct place})=1$, so proceed.

Thus obtained formula is so common it is called derangements, $!n$ or $D(n)$:
$$!n=n!\left[1-\frac1{2!}+\frac1{3!}...\frac.{n!}\right]$$